# Extract coefficients from symbolic expression

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, coefficients

Let

`syms h`

`g=exp(h)+h*exp(h)+h^2`

so, the coefficients of `g` in respect to `h`is given by the function `coeffs`:

`coeffs(g,h)`

and it returns:

`[exp(h),exp(h),1]`

It's like this function deals with the symbolic expression like a polynomial in `h`.

The problem is that this function doesnt return the zero coefficients, so if I have an

`g=h*exp(h)+h^2`

the function returns only:

`[exp(h), 1]`.

But what I need is:

`[0,exp(h), 1]`

So, what can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be one of those posters that lectures, but this is listed right in the Matlab help (`help coeff`) or [online](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/coeffs.html#bu5jr5z-6)

```
coeffs(g,h, 'All')
```

Comment: I think you mean `coeffs(g,h,'All')` since `coeff` doesnt exist. The problem with the function `coeffs` is that you cannot enter with three arguments, it only accepts two. Have you tested your answer?

Comment: Yes I tested it. I just retyped it because it was so short. Follow that link and you'll see it's an option.

Answer (score 0):

I went to a lot of topics on SO and the solution is:

```
syms  h
g=h*exp(h)+h^2
m = eval(feval(symengine,'coeff',g,h,'All'));
```